# Cannot install vmware-view-client on 13.04 amd64

Tags: vmware

New install 13.04 amd64

```
OptiPlex-7010:~$ sudo apt-get install vmware-view-client 

[sudo] password for xxxxxxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vmware-view-client:i386 : Depends: libudev0:i386 (>= 147) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried--

```
OptiPlex-7010:~$ sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386
[sudo] password for xxxxxxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libudev0:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libudev0:i386' has no installation candidate
```

ran  `sudo apt-get upgrade`,
tried again, same failure

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 13.04, Canonical chose not to repackage/include libudev0:i386. ("aptitude search libudev0" won't return a result). However, the binary is still available for 12.10, which can be found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/libudev0/download
You don't need anything else for vmware view install and run perfectly on 13.04

Comment: Yep, this works on Ubuntu 13.04, 64-bit. Thank you! Hopefully this will be accepted as the answer.

Comment: This will also work for 14.04. Small note that an amd64 package is also offered: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libudev0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the i386 package of vmware. There is at the moment no amd64 package available. 
To make it work on the ubuntu 13.04 64bit I found this great post on mbentley.net:
http://blog.mbentley.net/2013/05/vmware-view-client-1-7-2-0-on-ubuntu-13-04-i386amd64/

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other solutions posted did not work for me, but fortunately I was able to download a new 64-bit release from VMware's website which has apparently fixed the dependency problem.  The name has changed to VMware Horizon View Client but it is the same product.  Download the [Ubuntu 64-bit version here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VIEWCLIENTS_LINUX64_210&productId=331&rPId=4171) and open in software center: